# tkinter and selenium how to send text to driver.get?

Tags: python, selenium, tkinter

on to send the text from entry driver.get ? what I'm doing wrong ?

def onclick():

txt = Entry(root)

txt.place(x=200, y=70)

texto = txt.get()

driver.get(texto)

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your code, as the answer depends on it

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait until the user has a chance to type into the entry widget. As written, you are calling `txt.get()` about a millisecond after creating the widget.

Typically you should call the `get` method in response to an event such as clicking a button or pressing the return key, or something like that.

Comment: but that's what I'm doing I guess... the def onclick its activated only after I click on the button

Comment: No, it's not what you're doing. You're clearly callint `txt.get()` just two lines after creating `txt`. Please double-check the code in your question. I had to add some formatting because what you posted wasn't readable, maybe I formatted it incorrectly.